# Redirect from subdomain to root domain not working as expected

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am currently working on a ruby on rails project and I am doing some raw javascript with jquery. I want to redirect my root domain, localhost:3000, from localhost:3000/home.

To achieve this I have to following code:

```
window.location.replace('localhost:3000');
```

This doesn't bring me back to my main page, but instead back to the homepage localhost:3000/home/ or does nothing.

However I tried a different domain, stackoverflow.com, and this worked

```
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

The url is valid so I don't know what could be wrong with redirecting to the localhost. Is this a security issue with the routing or does this have to do with the fact that I am working on a localhost? Any help on this manner would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you point a web browser at http://localhost:3000/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing "http://" in your url.

```
window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: Yes this worked. I didn't realize it redirected locally so the http was necessary. For example if I were just to put have window.location.replace('stackoverflow.com');
it would redirect me to 'localhost:3000/stackoverflow.com'. Thank you